# Generic Repository Loc

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am learning Entity Framework and trying out the generic repository with worker pattern. Using **Castle Windsor** I am injecting everything through interfaces.

However the unit of work property InternetRepository is tightly coupled:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed> InternetSpeedRepository { get; }
    void Save();
}

public class UnitOfWork :IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;
    private InternetSpeedEntities context = new InternetSpeedEntities();

    private IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed> internetSpeedRepository;
    public IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed> InternetSpeedRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.internetSpeedRepository == null)
            {
                this.internetSpeedRepository = new GenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed>(context);
            }
            return internetSpeedRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

How do I inject this property to use an interface? Further below is how `IUnitOfWork` is called:

```
    private Timer timer;
    private ICalculateInternetSpeed internetSpeed;
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public MyRunner(ICalculateInternetSpeed internetSpeed, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.internetSpeed = internetSpeed;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer = new Timer
                    {
                        //1000 (1 sec)
                        Interval = 5000,
                        Enabled = true
                    };

        timer.Elapsed += (TimerElapsed);
    }

   public void Stop()
   {

   }

   private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           timer.Enabled = false;
           //Kick off method to get the download speed
           var speed = internetSpeed.CalculateInternetDownloadSpeed();
           Logger.Logger.Info("Internet Speed calculated.");
           unitOfWork.InternetSpeedRepository.Insert(speed);
           unitOfWork.Save();
           Logger.Logger.Info(string.Format("Inserted record with ID {0} into the database.", speed.RecordId));
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
       }
       finally
       {
           timer.Enabled = true;
       }
   }
}
```

This is then called inside my program's main class:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        var runner = container.Resolve<IMyRunner>();

        HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<IMyRunner>(s =>
                    {
                        s.SetServiceName(ServiceName);
                        s.ConstructUsing(c => runner);
                        s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                        s.WhenStopped(tc =>
                            {
                                tc.Stop();
                                container.Release(runner);
                            });
                    });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetDescription(ServiceDescription);
                x.SetDisplayName(ServiceDisplayName);
                x.SetServiceName(ServiceName);
                x.StartAutomatically();

            });
    }
```

One last code snippet that I think is required is my installer class:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyRunner>().ImplementedBy<MyRunner>().LifeStyle.Transient,
                           Component.For<ICalculateInternetSpeed>().ImplementedBy<CalculateInternetSpeed>().LifeStyle.Transient,
                           Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>().LifeStyle.Transient,
                           Component.For<ISimpleWebClient>().ImplementedBy<SimpleWebClient>(),
                           Component.For<IConfig>().ImplementedBy<Config>(),
                           Component.For<IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed>>().ImplementedBy<GenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed>>());
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried to inject it here but not sure if this would work. Is this the correct way of doing the property injection?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to register `InternetSpeedEntities` as well.
Then, either accept `IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed>` as a parameter in the Unit of Work constructor and set the private field, or convert that property to an automatic property with getter and setter and Castle Windsor will do the work for you.

Few other notes though:

- Try to get used to registering your components via conventions (for example, `container.Register(
              Classes.FromThisAssembly()
              .Pick().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()

              );`)
  That way you don't have to do everything manually..
- Pay attention to the life style of your components. If you don't specify one - It's a singleton by default. Those won't be disposed until the container is disposed. Alternatively you can bind the lifestyle of a component to a parent object type up the object graph.

Hope this helps, good luck!

**-EDIT-**

As an **example**, your `UnitOfWork` could look like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public UnitOfWork(GenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed> repository, InternetSpeedEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.InternetSpeedRepository = repository;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;
    private InternetSpeedEntities context;

    public IGenericRepository<RecordInternetSpeed> InternetSpeedRepository { get; private set; }

    ...

}
```

And your Installer could look something like this:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick().WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient()
            );
    }
}
```

The repository and context are *dependencies* of your `UnitOfWork`. As long as windsor knows how to create them, it will supply them to the constructor during the resolve process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any code example I can refer to? With your suggestion?

Comment: Are you referring to my notes or the direct answer to your question?

Comment: Yours note are very good. I mean the direct answer to this question.

Comment: I put this in the installer file but the unitofwork will no longer work because LifestyleTransient creates new instance every time the object is called. How could I fix this? I fixed by removing .LifestyleTransient() in the installer. Does this make sense?

Comment: Removing `.LifestyleTransient` is equal to writing `.LifestyleSingleton`.  If this is the behavior you wanted, then yes. Please note though, that singleton objects are not released by calling the release method. They stick around for the life time of the container.

Comment: Ok thanks how would I make all the objects transient apart from the generic repository and unit of work?

Comment: By using ConfigureFor. Listen, you should really go through the docs.. There's only so much you can learn from SO comments ;-)